# TextView character limit in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview, character

I'm doing a book reader with a viewpager which contains fragments. Inside every fragment i have a textView
with a part of the book simulating a page of that book. The problem is that i can't find out how to find the right limit of characters for each fragment so it can be proper page. I'm puttin now for example a 600 char limit per page but i would like to know if there is any better way to set that limit per page.

This is the viewPager adapter where i take the whole book string and convert it into pages according to the partition size of chars i set (in this case 600):

```
public class StackAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int charMax;
    private String content;
    private List<String> parts;

    public StackAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int charMax, String content) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.charMax = charMax;
        this.content = content;
        this.parts = getParts(content, charMax);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return parts.size();
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position, parts.get(position));
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }


    private List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize) {
        List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += partitionSize) {
            parts.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
        }
        return parts;
    }
    
}
```

This is how i create the adapter in the main activity:

```
//Result variable is a string with the book's content.
StackAdapter adapterViewPager = new StackAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 600, result);
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]